# Cast Bindingsoure.Current to POCO

Tags: c#, data-binding, ado.net, poco, bindingsource

I have a sqldatareader that gets assigned to a bindingsource and a datagridview datasource to that.

When I look at the type of Bindingsoure.Current its a DataRecordInternal.  How can I cast that to my POCO?

Will I have to manually work out which fields in the Current object relate to my POCO.  I could do it through my POCO and just take the Grid.Cells[0]["ID"] and populate it that way but that is obviosuly another hit to the DB.